# How can I create a public list of event attendees?

Tags: wordpress, civievent

I would like to create a page on my Wordpress site that lists everyone who is registered for a specific event (EID 3 in this case). I only need a list of attendees names, sort by last name. No other columns needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using profiles

1. Create a smart group of all attendees of the event
2. Create manage acl to grant view permission for authenticated and anonymous user to view contacts from smart group.
3. Create a profile for search and include fields that you want to show.
4. Create manage acl to use the above  created profile for search for anonymous user
5. Create a post/page on wordpress and include profile search short code.

Also you can use [content views wordpress](https://github.com/agileware/content-views-civicrm-data-processor) instead profile to show contact belonging to smart group